# How can I absolutely position a block of multi-line text relative to the bottom of the last line?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a problem that seems like it should be solvable using CSS - it's conceptually simple and I'd assume a relatively common problem, but how to achieve it is eluding me at the moment!

I have a container spanning 100% width and 100% height, and I need to absolutely position a block of text which have a variable number of lines so that the bottom of the bottom line of the text block is at a fixed vertical position in the container. I can only seem to position it relative to the top of the text, which is no good as it sometimes overflows out of the container when there are more lines.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/l3ftblank/be73v/) of my failed attempt at positioning relative to the top of the text.

CSS:

```
html, body, l-container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.l-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;    
}

.caption {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: -180px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 82%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="l-container">
    <div class="caption">Multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multilinemultilinemultilinemultiline
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Does anybody know if this is achievable in pure CSS? I'd rather not have to use JS for layout, but this problem is making me tear my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `bottom: 0` and leave out any `top` styling, the absolutely positioned div should expand up.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question, it sounds like you need absolute positioning. Your CSS is only showing relative positioning.

Replace this CSS:

```
.caption {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: -180px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 82%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

...with this:

```
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: -180px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

See an example in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/be73v/1/

On an unrelated note, might I suggest you add "margin: 0; padding: 0;" to your "html, body, l-container" css to remove the unnecessary scrollbars.